# Socket.io examples with Swift and Node.js on the backend

Tags: ios, swift, socket.io

I am trying to find a working example of a Socket.io implementation on iOS with Swift, but have been unlucky so far. I did get a few examples from Github, but each have some issues and I cannot tell why they don’t work.

Does anyone know where I can get an out of the box working example, so that I can go through the code and understand the implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I asked the question there have been changes and we now have socket.io for iOS. Here's the original blog post on it: http://socket.io/blog/socket-io-on-ios/

Answer (score 5):

Based on socket.io's examples:

Server (index.js, see socket.io website for setup):

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        io.emit('chat message', msg);
    });
});

http.listen(8080, function(){
   console.log('listening on *:8080');
});
```

Client (ViewController.swift):

```
import UIKit
import Socket_IO_Client_Swift

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var chatView:UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var sendButton:UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var sendField:UITextField!

let socket = SocketIOClient(socketURL: "10.0.0.1:8080", opts: ["log": true])

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    addHandlers()
    self.socket.connect()
}

@IBAction func send() {
    self.socket.emit("chat message", withItems: [self.sendField.text!])
    self.sendField.text = ""
}

func addHandlers() {
    self.socket.on("connect") {data, ack in
        print("socket connected")
    }

    self.socket.on("chat message") {[weak self] data, ack in
        if let value = data.first as? String {
            self?.chatView.text?.appendContentsOf(value + "\n")
        }
    }
}
}
```

Web client (index.html, useful for testing):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
      body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
      form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
      form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
      form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      var socket = io();
      $('form').submit(function(){
        socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
        $('#m').val('');
        return false;
      });
      socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thats a great example. can you please tell me how to send images from one client and receive in others. From iOS end i can make image to nsdata/base64String anything you want and at receiving end I can receive it and convert it back. I want to know the server implementation. What to write there so that image goes there and then it send it back. Its very urgent. Please help.